# After update Epiphany stopped working

Tags: release-hera, shutdown, epiphany

After OS and Epiphany updates, Epiphany stopped working. Installed Firefox and it worked fine. OS became unstable also: shutdown hangs; starting the system tools app also hangs; must power off. Is there some log where one can look into what might be going on. Thanks. Best.

---

Here goes:

```
rui@rui-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:~$ dmesg | tail
[   48.851081]  worker_thread+0x32/0x410
[   48.851084]  kthread+0x121/0x140
[   48.851085]  ? process_one_work+0x420/0x420
[   48.851086]  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
[   48.851088]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[   48.851089] Code: a0 00 00 00 c1 e8 02 89 c3 4c 89 ff e8 1d ed fa d4 89 da 44 01 f3 81 fb f7 03 00 00 48 8d 04 95 00 00 00 00 76 7a 49 8b 44 24 38 <c7> 04 90 00 00 00 20 49 8b 74 24 18 48 85 f6 74 74 31 ff e8 9b 
[   48.851137] RIP: evo_wait+0x5d/0x130 [nouveau] RSP: ffffa45801b4fbe8
[   48.851137] CR2: ffff98738a84e100
[   48.851139] ---[ end trace bb9bc699e1b7a957 ]---
[   48.851376] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: channel 0 killed!
```

neofetch

```
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            rui@rui-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop 
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee         ------------------------- 
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee       OS: elementary OS 5.1 Hera x86_64 
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee     Host: OMEN by HP Laptop 
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee    Kernel: 4.15.0-72-generic 
eee    eee            eee       eee   Uptime: 6 mins 
eee   eee            eee        eee   Packages: 1843 
ee    eee           eeee       eeee   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee   Resolution: 3200x1800 
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee   DE: Pantheon 
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee   WM: Mutter(Gala) 
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee   Theme: Elementary [GTK3] 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee    Icons: Elementary [GTK3] 
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee     Terminal: io.elementary.t 
    eeeee                 eeeee       CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ (8) @ 3.800GHz 
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee 
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

---

After installing a 'non-curated' NVIDIA driver everything went back to normal. Thanks for formatting my garbled dump.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, post the output for `dmesg | tail`... (not enough reputation to comment).
Also the output of `neofetch` after installing it with `sudo apt neofetch`.

> Just `Select`, `Copy` from terminal & `Paste` in your question.