# Epiphany web browser not working after update

Tags: epiphany

I'm new to elementary OS (but not to Linux/Ubuntu) and installed it for the first time today. Looks very nice but I have the first strange issue. After installing eOS the Web Browser (Epiphany) worked fine. After updating the system through AppCenter I got an endlessly spinning page loading icon. Firefox works fine though. I found [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21889/after-update-epiphany-stopped-working) but it's related to NVIDIA and quite old. I have an Intel GPU.

```
user@HPSpectre13X360:~$ neofetch
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            family@HPSpectre13X360 
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee         ---------------------- 
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee       OS: elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir x86_64 
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee     Host: HP Spectre 13 X360 Convertible 
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee    Kernel: 5.15.0-57-generic 
eee    eee            eee       eee   Uptime: 14 mins 
eee   eee            eee        eee   Packages: 1572 (dpkg), 12 (flatpak) 
ee    eee           eeee       eeee   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee   Resolution: 2560x1440 
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee   DE: Pantheon 
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee   WM: Mutter(Gala) 
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee   Theme: io.elementary.stylesheet.blueberry [GTK3] 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee    Icons: elementary [GTK3] 
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee     Terminal: io.elementary.t 
    eeeee                 eeeee       CPU: Intel i7-5500U (4) @ 3.000GHz 
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee         GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5500 
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            Memory: 1008MiB / 7857MiB
```

dmesg shows this error all over

```
[ 1832.905697] traps: eadedCompositor[42368] trap int3 ip:7fe3038caf27 sp:7fe28fffddd0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7400.1[7fe303887000+95000]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Update:
As per the answer below I installed coredumpctl. Now I get this

```
family@HPSpectre13X360:~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
|/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t 9223372036854775808 %h
family@HPSpectre13X360:~$ sudo su
root@HPSpectre13X360:/home/family# coredumpctl gdb
           PID: 38010 (WebKitWebProces)
           UID: 1000 (family)
           GID: 1000 (family)
        Signal: 5 (TRAP)
     Timestamp: Sat 2023-01-14 21:29:05 CET (9s ago)
  Command Line: /usr/libexec/webkit2gtk-4.1/WebKitWebProcess 284 26
    Executable: /usr/libexec/webkit2gtk-4.1/WebKitWebProcess
 Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app-flatpak-org.gnome.Epiphany-37999.scope
          Unit: user@1000.service
     User Unit: app-flatpak-org.gnome.Epiphany-37999.scope
         Slice: user-1000.slice
     Owner UID: 1000 (family)
       Boot ID: e3bb3d5594c849738401466cab790526
    Machine ID: c6835bfbf14764bf68e1123c63b95333
      Hostname: HPSpectre13X360
       Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.WebKitWebProces.1000.e3bb3d5594c849738401466cab790526.38010.1673728145000000000000.lz4 (truncated)
       Message: Process 38010 (WebKitWebProces) of user 1000 dumped core.
                
                Stack trace of thread 11:
                #0  0x00007f057a74bf27 n/a (n/a + 0x0)


Failed to invoke gdb: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
-- Notice: 1 systemd-coredump@.service unit is running, output may be incomplete.
root@HPSpectre13X360:/home/family#
```

Not sure what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

> [ 1832.905697] traps: eadedCompositor[42368] trap int3 ip:7fe3038caf27 sp:7fe28fffddd0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7400.1[7fe303887000+95000]

It's crashing. Follow [these instructions](https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2021/09/18/creating-quality-backtraces-for-crash-reports/) to get a useful crash report so you can report a bug.

Comment: Thanks, but somehow I'm struggling with coredumpctl (updated question above)